# Is there PAAS hosting platforms for event driven applications?

Tags: node.js, heroku, twisted, event-driven, paas

I am looknig for a PAAS hosting service to deploy my small event-driven and websocket server applications (NodeJS, Python Twisted, etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're pretty much all in beta and I'm pretty sure I'm forgetting about a couple of them, but here's a list.

- http://www.duostack.com/
- https://no.de/
- http://www.nodejitsu.com/
- http://nodester.com/
- http://cloud9ide.com/
- http://www.nodesocket.com